# Having problem in Amadeus flight search time zone and flight duration looking for API

Tags: amadeus

Facing problem when fetching amadeus flight search api. When fetching flights details for two different timezone unable to see "Flight Duration" in the response we are receving. Got confused weather we can get flight duration in the API response or we should have to calculate it manually

Comment: Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: lightInformation] => stdClass Object
 ( [productDateTime] => stdClass Object
                                                                        (
[dateOfDeparture] => 060219
[timeOfDeparture] => 1320
[dateOfArrival] => 060219
[timeOfArrival] => 1500

Comment: Not getting flight duration only getting departure and arrival time when i hit the api

Comment: Are you using the Flight Low-fare Search, the Flight Inspiration Search or the Flight Cheapest date? Could you please provide the API call(s) you are doing?

Comment: we are using this api 
Fare_MasterPricerTravelboardSearch

Answer (score 1):

Fare_MasterPricerTravelboardSearch reply also contains information about an itinerary travel duration.

You may find it in `groupOfFlights/propFlightGrDetail/flightProposal` node where `unitQualifier` equals to EFT (Elapsed Flying Time).

Please note, that this is a total time for all legs of the itinerary.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Air_FlightInfo.
You can find the flight duration in:
Air_FlightInfoReply -> flightScheduleDetails -> boardPointAndOffPointDetails -> additionalProductDetails -> legDetails -> duration
It will be in the format hhmm.